# Scala: remove first column (first element in each row)

Tags: arrays, scala, seq

Given an `var x: Array[Seq[Any]]`, what would be the most efficient (fast, in-place if possible?) way to remove the first element from each row?

I've tried the following but it didn't work - probably because of immutability...

```
  for (row <- x.indices)
    x(row).drop(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `Array`s are mutable, and I'm guessing you're intending to change the *elements* of `x`, rather than replacing the entire array with a new array object, so it makes more sense to use `val` instead of `var`:

```
val x: Array[Seq[Any]]
```

Since you said your `Seq` objects are immutable, then you need to make sure you are *setting* the values in your array. This will work:

```
for (row <- x.indices)
  x(row) = x(row).drop(1)
```

This can be written in nicer ways. For example, you can use [`transform`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray@transform(f:A=%3EA):SeqLike.this.type) to map all the values of your array with a function:

```
x.transform(_.drop(1))
```

This updates in-place, unlike `map`, which will leave the old array unmodified and return a new array.

EDIT: I started to speculate on which method would be faster or more efficient, but the more I think about it, the more I realize I'm not sure. Both should have acceptable performance for most use cases.

Comment: nice, very comprehensive and educational - thanks for this answer

Comment: as a follow up question, if you don't mind - if `transform(...)` is modifying elements in-place, then how does this work for `val`?
Is there an equivalent for `transform(...)` but for 1D array or seq?

Comment: map, which will leave the old array unmodified and return a new array, but the new array and the old array will share same elements, that's why immutable data structures are so important.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the memory footprint for shared elements is not increased with such mapping operation?

Comment: `val` means you can't assign `x` to refer to a different array object. I'm not sure what you mean about an equivalent to `transform` for a 1D array, because `x` *is* a 1D `Array`.

Comment: Dan - `x` is the array of `Seq`s, I've meant e.g. `Array[Int]`

Comment: Well, I don't see the difference; both are `Array`s. For example you could do `myIntArray.transform(_ + 1)` to increment all the values in an int array.

Comment: I can see how to drop the element with `myIntArray = myIntArray.drop(1)`, but I don't immediately see how your in-place solution with `val` can apply here

Comment: Dropping elements? Now I'm confused. Do you want to drop elements from an array? If so, yes, you need a `var`, or a type other than `Array`, because you cannot change the length of an array.

Comment: sorry for confusion... Yes, i've meant something similar to `transform(...)` which could drop the element. Now all is clear, though. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

this would work

```
scala> val x = Array(List(1,2,3),List(1,2,3))
x: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))

scala> x map(_.drop(1))
res0: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(2, 3), List(2, 3))
```